# Line breaks not working properly with Laravel Text Emails / Testing in Mailhog

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

If I understood correctly, in laravel text emails it is not necessary to add "\n" for example,

but it seems that, some times the "enters" ( new lines ) I add work properly, sometimes not.

I've been trying to figure it out anc it is a mystery, seen some people with the same issue but haven't found a solution yet.

Some examples/tests below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:

HTML is not being used! I'm calling ->text( and not->view(:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added 2 spaces BEFORE the line break, Issue solved.
Make sure your IDE is not trimming spaces at the end!!
Which was my case with VSCode ( not sure if some plugin or native will figure out soon )

Comment: hmm - This did not work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

You are using Blade Template from Laravel, and Blade uses html tags.
In your case, since you are using HTML anyway, why not use breaklines, paragraphs, divs or anything that is a block element so that you can efficiently add a newline.

```
<p>
<br>
<div>
```

Or much better approach is to use Markdown template for Emails as documented from official Laravel page, [Markdown mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#generating-markdown-mailables)

Comment: That is not true I am not using "HTML anyways" , I am calling ->text( and not ->view( . And I can also prove to you HTML is not being used ( will Edit post and add 2 more images at the end, added HTML tags and they do not take effect ). But I will consider the markdown thing and get back to you.

Comment: I don't want / need markdown feature, I want simple text email, with proper line breaks ^^